# hexToBinary dictionary

Tags: python, algorithm

So I am working on this problem: Recall from the Number Systems unit the method for converting hexadecimal numbers to
binary by converting each hex digit to its equivalent four binary digits. Write a Python
function named hexToBinary with parameters (number, table) that uses this algorithm to
convert a hexadecimal number to a (return) binary number. The algorithm visits each digit
in the hexadecimal number, selecting from table the corresponding four bits that represent
that digit in binary and then adds these bits to the result string.

This is the code I have written, but I'm not getting it able to work properly:

```
def hexToBinary (hex, table):
    hexToBinary= {'0':'0000', '1':'0001', '2':'0010','3':'0011', '4': '0100', '5': '0101', '6':'0110', '7': '0111', '8': '1000', '9': '1001', 'A': '1010', 'B': '1011', 'C': '1100', 'D': '1101', 'E': '1110', 'F': '1111'}
    final_hexToBinary = ''
    for hex in hexToBinary:
        final_hexToBinary+=hex
        print(final_hexToBinary)
```

I am wondering what is wrong with the function, I have a feeling it is a simple mistake.

Comment: what is table in here???

Comment: It would be helpful to see your test input and the incorrect output.

Comment: @Hackaholic, the table is defined, hexToBinary, it is the dictionary

Comment: @CraigAnderson, currently im not getting back an output, it stops at the for loop :/

Comment: waht is hex in here?? can you show expected input and expected output

Comment: From your question it seems,You should be iterating the hex instead. The table should be created in some other function and passed.

Comment: Do you really need the table? `bin(int(your_hex_code, 16))[2:]` or http://docs.python.org/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify can solve it?

Comment: @hackaholic test hexToBinary("3FB", hexToBinaryTable) --> 001111111011

Comment: @MustafaKadadah chek my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def hexToBinary (hex, table):

    final_hexToBinary = ''
    for each  in hex:
        final_hexToBinary+=table[each]
    print(final_hexToBinary)
hexToBinaryTable = {'0':'0000', '1':'0001', '2':'0010','3':'0011', '4': '0100', '5': '0101', '6':'0110', '7': '0111', '8': '1000', '9': '1001', 'A': '1010', 'B': '1011', 'C': '1100', 'D': '1101', 'E': '1110', 'F': '1111'}
hexToBinary("3FB",hexToBinaryTable)
```

As mentioned it comment your might want to look up the dictionary.
If you need not implement the function go for the one mentioned by john galt in comment.

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it

Comment: Follow the points in other answers as well, Regarding using hex.

Answer (score 2):

You forget this:

```
final_hexToBinary += hexToBinary[hex]
```

Also:

- 'table' -- not used var.
- hexToBinary name of function and dict.
- hex -- reserved word, argument and iterator.

It's not a problem, but sometime you can achieve mistake with that.

Comment: there are more mistake too, OP is iterating `dict` instead of hex variable

Comment: Actually i tried it, but it still didn't work :/ thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

if I am correct you are trying this:

```
def hexToBinary(my_hex):
    hexToBinary= {'0':'0000', '1':'0001', '2':'0010','3':'0011', '4': '0100', '5': '0101', '6':'0110', '7': '0111', '8': '1000', '9': '1001', 'A': '1010', 'B': '1011', 'C': '1100', 'D': '1101', 'E': '1110', 'F': '1111'}
    final_hexToBinary = ''
    for x in my_hex:    # here it should be my_hex instead of table
        final_hexToBinary += hexToBinary[x]  # here was the mistake
    print(final_hexToBinary)

hexToBinary("ABC12")
```

output:

```
10101011110000010010
```

## NOTE: dont use `hex`  as variable name its built-in python

Comment: Thank you everyone! Great help and advice

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```py
hexToBinary= {'0':'0000', '1':'0001', '2':'0010','3':'0011', '4': '0100', '5': '0101', '6':'0110', '7': '0111', '8': '1000', '9': '1001', 'A': '1010', 'B': '1011', 'C': '1100', 'D': '1101', 'E': '1110', 'F': '1111'}
to_conv= input("enter a num: ")
final_hexToBinary = ''
for hex in to_conv:
    final_hexToBinary += hexToBinary.get(hex,"!!") + " "
print(final_hexToBinary)
```

Comment: Hi there  This answer is almost indistinguishable from two answers that are already listed here (except it uses `.get` instead of a `[]` dictionary lookup). Take a look at [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), it's usually best to focus on well-asked questions when you're getting started with answering on StackOverflow.